# C++ Minimax Algorithm for Connect Four stuck in infinite loop (I think)

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, minimax

I am currently attempting to code a connect 4 AI that uses the minimax algorithm to play optimally. However, it seems to currently be stuck in an infinite loop, definitely being caused by the minimax function shown here.

Each recursive call is closer to the base case since every time the minimax function is called, one more cell in the grid will be filled in. This makes the grid one step closer to either having a winner, or being filled up with no winner. And, after the for loop iterates and calls minimax through all cells of the grid, the function should return.

Things I have tried:

- Reducing the depth variable
- Reducing board size (it was previously 5x5, now it is 4x4)
- Changing values of variables 'best' and 'worst'
- Changing the function that checks if there is a winner

My guess is that for some reason, some of the calls to minimax are never reaching their base case. Any help as to what is going on would be greatly appreciated.

Code here (fixed formatting):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

pair<bool, char> isWinner(std::vector<std::vector<char> >& grid, char aiMark, char hMark) {

//bool = whether game is concluded, char = winner of game, 
'-' if none. An unfinished game will always be {false, '-'}.

  pair<bool, char> temp;
  temp.first = true;
  temp.second = '-';

//checks whether board is full, if it is full, temp is changed to {true, '-'} until one of the other for loops is triggered

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if(grid[i][j] != '-') {
             temp.first = (temp.first && true);
          
        } else {
            temp.first = (temp.first && false);
            }
        }
    }

//horizontal 4-in-a-row check
   
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if (grid[i][0] == aiMark && grid[i][1] == aiMark && grid[i][2] == aiMark && grid[i][3] == aiMark){
            temp.first = true;
            temp.second = aiMark;
            return temp;
        } else if (grid[i][0] == hMark && grid[i][1] == hMark && grid[i][2] == hMark && grid[i][3] == hMark) {
            temp.first = true;
            temp.second = hMark;
            return temp;
        }           
    }
    
    //vertical 4-in-a-row check
    
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        if (grid[0][j] == aiMark && grid[1][j] == aiMark && grid[2][j] == aiMark && grid[3][j] == aiMark){
            temp.first = true;
            temp.second = aiMark;
            return temp;
        } else if (grid[0][j] == hMark && grid[1][j] == hMark && grid[2][j] == hMark && grid[3][j] == hMark){
            temp.first = true;
            temp.second = hMark;
            return temp;
        }           
    }
    
     
   //upwards diagonal check
       
    if (grid[3][0] == aiMark && grid[2][1] == aiMark && grid[1][2] == aiMark && grid[0][3] == aiMark) {
        temp.first = true;
        temp.second = aiMark;
        return temp;
    } else if (grid[3][0] == hMark && grid[2][1] == hMark && grid[1][2] == hMark && grid[0][3] == hMark) {
        temp.first = true;
        temp.second = hMark;
        return temp;
    } 
                
        
    
    //downwards diagonal check
   
    if (grid[3][3] == aiMark && grid[2][2] == aiMark && grid[1][1] == aiMark && grid[0][0] == aiMark) {
        temp.first = true;
        temp.second = aiMark;
        return temp;
    } else if (grid[3][3] == hMark && grid[2][2] == hMark && grid[1][1] == hMark && grid[0][0] == hMark) {
        temp.first = true;
        temp.second = hMark;
        return temp;
    }
                
        
    
    return temp;
    

}


int minimax(std::vector<std::vector<char> >& grid, int depth, bool maxim, char aiMark, char hMark) {
//grid = connect-4 board, depth = current depth of the minimax call, maxim = if the current player is maximizing, aiMark = X, hMark = O


    pair<bool, char> result = isWinner(grid, aiMark, hMark);
   
   
    
    if(result.first != false) { //if the game is concluded

        if(result.second == aiMark) { //maximizing player wins
            return depth;
        } else if (result.second == hMark) { //max. player loses
            return -depth;
        } else { //tie
            return 0;
    }

        

    } else {
        
        if(maxim == true) { //maximizing player's turn
            int best = -17;

            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
         

                    if(grid[i][j] == '-') { //check if space is empty
          
                        grid[i][j] = aiMark;
            
                        int score = minimax(grid, depth - 1, !maxim, aiMark, hMark); //call minimax with new grid + other player's turn
                        best = max(best, score); //update best score
                        grid[i][j] = '-'; //backtrack

                   

                }
            
            }
        }
        

        return best; //return the best possible score
    

    } else {
        int worst = 17;

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

                if(grid[i][j] == '-') {
                    grid[i][j] = hMark;
                    int score = minimax(grid, depth - 1, !maxim, aiMark, hMark);
                    worst = min(worst, score);
                     grid[i][j] = '-';

                   
                    }
            
            

                }
            }


        return worst; //return worst score for maximizing player
        }

    }

    

}


void bestMove(std::vector<std::vector<char> >& grid,  char aiMark, char hMark) {

    int best = -17;
    int finalRow;
    int finalCol;

    pair<bool, char> result = isWinner(grid, aiMark, hMark);
    
    if(result.first != false) { //if game is concluded
      return;
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
     

            if(grid[i][j] == '-') { //check if space is empty
          
                grid[i][j] = aiMark; //place mark in row/column
                int score = minimax(grid, 16, true, aiMark, hMark); //the 'score' player will get from placing their mark here
                if(score > best) {
                    best = score;
                    finalRow = i;
                    finalCol = j; //update best score and best row/column accordingly
                }
                grid[i][j] = '-'; //backtrack
            
               
                
            }
        

               

        }
    }

    grid[finalRow][finalCol] = aiMark; //change the best row + best column square to the player's mark
    return;
    

}
```

Comment: Have you tried yourself to solve the problem? For example, you'd want to make the code easier to read first - why would you write `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++ )` if this is just one iteration?

Comment: help us help you :) formatting is not just for nice-ness, many times fixing the obvious things would reveal the actual problem.

Comment: Fixed some code formatting issues.

Comment: When it comes to connect-based games, you can easily fall into endless loops if you don't properly track already visited cells so you don't visit them again. I recommend checking out the [flood-fill algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flood-fill-algorithm-implement-fill-paint/) so you get the gist of the idea.

Comment: Also be sure to comment your code.  I see a wall of code but not much to go on to understand the thought and intent of the code.

Comment: I am not sure why I would  have to keep track of already visited cells, as the recursion only triggers when a cell's value is the 'blank' value, '-' in this case. Every time the recursion happens at a blank cell, that cell's value becomes one of X or O. Eventually, either a winner has to be declared or the board is filled with no winner(tie).

Comment: Side note: while comments are good, descriptive identifiers and the replacing of magic numbers with named constants is better. Try to write code that comments itself and you'll find you can all-but eliminate whole families of bugs and still more become obvious if you make them.

Comment: Added comments to code

Comment: *"it seems to currently be stuck in an infinite loop,"* -- infinite loop or infinite recursion? If it is a loop, which loop?

Comment: *"some of the calls to minimax are never reaching their base case."* -- what is the base case (in words, not code)? Why do you believe the base case should be reached? What ensures that you are making progress with each recursive call?

Comment: Base case: there is a winner, or the game ends in a tie. I think the code is stuck in an infinite recursion.

Comment: @EdricAntoine Next step: prove that each recursive call is closer to the base case than the previous call. *(Example: recursive quicksort always makes progress towards the base case [0-length array] by ensuring that the recursive call handles strictly fewer elements. What is the analogous control in your code?)*

Comment: Probably not the root of your does-not-return problem, but using depth as the score does not really make sense. A deeper win (or loss) is no better (or worse) than a shallow one. Here, since you're not limiting the search depth, there should really be just three possible scores returned, -1, 1, or 0, for a win, loss, or a tie.

Comment: Each recursive call is closer to the base case since every time the minimax function is called, one more cell in the grid will be filled in. This makes the grid one step closer to either having a winner, or being filled up with no winner. And, after the for loop iterates and calls minimax through all cells of the grid, the function should return.

Comment: @EdricAntoine OK, that explanation looks solid (maybe should be in the question as well?). So the next thing I would look at is the "seems to" qualification you used. What makes you believe the recursion is infinite? Did you witness a recursive call repeat itself? Or did you just not wait long enough for a result? You are doing a recursive call for each unplayed space. If one space was filled in by the human player before this function was called, then we're looking at 15! calls to `minimax`. Even at 1 microsecond per 10 calls, that's about 1.5 days to finish. Did you wait that long?

Comment: Fun fact: while your code could make over a trillion calls to `minimax` to analyze board positions, there are less than 50 million possible board positions (and that includes board positions that are not possible in a game, such as every space filled by one player).

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I'm guessing there's not much I can do? I am out of any ideas to make this algorithm more efficient. I considered a memorization approach where I have an array that memorizes score values for a certain row, column and depth, but I only see that helping on the ai's 2nd or more turn. I am considering just reducing the board size to 3x3 and making it tic-tac-toe instead of connect 4.